# Get 1 document at a time inside a Firestore collection, without passing any key or filter, just by the order in which they where added?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore collection 'A', has inside many objects that have a unique name that start with 'A', example: {name:'Ants', imageLink:''},{name:'Arms', imageLink:''},etc. How to go on the list one by one as the user requests it, because he will have to modify each object. It is necessary to get the next document after the last one obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic ordering of documents by insertion/creation order on Cloud Firestore. If you want to allow retrieving the most recent document, you'll have to add a field with the insertion date/time yourself.

Once you do that, you can get the latest document with this query:

```
var doc = await firestore
  .collection("A")
  .orderBy("created_at", descending: true)
  .limit(1)
  .get()
```

You can get the next document by running a `startAfter` query:

```
var next = await firestore
  .collection("A")
  .orderBy("created_at", descending: true)
  .startAfter(doc)
  .limit(1)
  .get()
```